# What is the correct way to receive an object as a string through ZeroMQ and then send it with zero-copy through another socket?

Tags: c++, string, pointers, zeromq

I am receiving a large, serialized, binary object using `ZeroMQ`:

```
std::unique_ptr<Message> input(CreateMessage());

if (Receive(input, "data") > 0) {
    std::string serialStr(static_cast<char*>(input->GetData()), input->GetSize());
}
```

How can I send this object through another socket avoiding the unnecessary **`memcpy`**:

```
std::unique_ptr<Message> output(CreateMessage(serialStr.length()));
memcpy(output->GetData(), serialStr.c_str(), serialStr.length());

fChannels.at("data2").at(0).Send(output);
```

Also, is it a good idea to use an **`std::string`** to contain a binary object, or should I use a **`void*`** instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you are doing is forwarding then you can use the same message, you can use something like :

```
std::unique_ptr<Message> input(CreateMessage());
if (Receive(input, "data") > 0)
{
    fChannels.at("data2").at(0).Send(input);
}
```

Alternatively you can look at the 4 argument message constructor to use an existing buffer as the message payload rather than copying.

Comment: What if i want to examine the message first (i.e. de-serialize it) and only forward it if it matches a certain criteria? Can i still in that case just forward the received message?

Also, in the above code example i guess you mean

    fChannels.at("data2").at(0).Send(input);

Comment: I did indeed. Creating a std::string from the buffer will make a copy and  leave the message unchanged so would work. A warning though, at some point in time after the `Send` call the contents of `input` will be deleted/freed by zeromq so make your string before then.